# ASP.NET Administration Tool error

Tags: asp.net

I created a blank DB using SQL Server Management Studio. Ran the aspnet_regsql command to add the necessary tables into the DB. Opened a new Website in VS and added below pieces of code to web.config.

1.

```
<appSettings> <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" /></appSettings>
```

2.

```
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
<authorization >
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

3.

```
   <connectionStrings><remove name="LocalSqlServer"/><add name="LocalSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=SiteAdminDB; Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/></connectionStrings>
```

I ran this line in cmd: "C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm

And typed http://localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\Forms authentication\&applicationUrl=/ in address bar

But I am getting a localhost refused to connect error. 
What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a firewall running on your machine?  If so, did you add a rule to allow traffic through port 8089?

Comment: @squillman I don't have a firewall running.

Comment: Is this new Web Application or existing one? Could you connect to above database using SSMS?

Comment: It's a new web app. I am connected to the DB, but am getting an error